# Number Theory and Abstract Algebra

Tags: reference-request

I am going to start studying abstract algebra soon. I haven't taken a course in number theory before. Since quite a lot of the examples/questions in textbooks on abstract algebra are derived from basic results in number theory, I'd like to review a bit of number theory from either a number theory book or an abtsract algebra book.

Any suggestions for a good book that may have a good chapter or two in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Bhattacharya's Basic Abstract Algerbra and read its preliminaries (chapter 1 section 2 & chapter 2 section 1). If you want to study more about number theory, you can also read Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory.